# Multidimensional Array with foreach + while

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, smarty

I need to create a multidimensional array with a foreach loop and a while loop.

The first array contains this:

```
Array
(

    [0] => 13-10-14
    [1] => 13-10-15
    [2] => 13-10-16
    [3] => 13-10-17
    [4] => 13-10-18
    [5] => 13-10-19
)
```

I need to make it look like this:

```
Array
(

    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 13-10-14
            [id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 012643
                    [1] => 012667
                    [2] => 013362
                    [3] => 016169
                    [4] => 016839
                    [5] => 035288
                    [6] => 035369
                    [7] => 037664
                    [8] => 038979
                    [9] => 039014
                    [10] => 039036
                    [11] => 039505
                )

        )

)
```

The first array I do a foreach loop with the second I need to make while as it is a sql query.

Here is the code:

```
foreach ($rs as $results) {

  $rowT = $db->query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE LIMIT 10");

  while ($rsT = $db->fetch_assoc($rowT)) {
     $results['id'][] = $rsT;
  }
   $l_array[] = $results;
}## Heading ##
print_r($l_array);
```

Is returning the error:

```
Fatal error: Can not use string offset to an array
```

Comment: you're going to be running the exact same query every time the foreach() loop iterates, so you'd be getting/saving the **SAME** id values each time. rather a pointless waste of resources. run the query outside the loop then just use its results within, saving yourself the repeated pointless querying.

Comment: Yes, but only in this example. I use a query with dinamic params each loop. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your $rs is this:

```
array([0] => 13-10-14
      [1] => 13-10-15
      [2] => 13-10-16
      [3] => 13-10-17
      [4] => 13-10-18
      [5] => 13-10-19)
```

Your foreach() would set $results to: 13-10-15, 13-10-16, etc.  I think that's your error, since those are strings, not arrays.  How about this:

```
$final_array = array();
foreach ($rs as $results) {
    $tmp_array = array('date'=>$results);
    $rowT = $db->query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE LIMIT 10");
    while ($rsT = $db->fetch_assoc($rowT)) {
       $tmp_array['id'][] = $rsT;
    }
    $final_array[] = $tmp_array;
}## Heading ##
print_r($final_array);
```